# linux - kernel thread preemption

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel

I've got some realtime linux kernel and I'm developing some code with kernel thread. This thread is called by ethernet interrupt handler. I noticed that every call of this thread takes about 100 jiffies. In this time it reads about 256 ethernet frames. The ethernet is 1Gbps and download speed which I measured is about 4MB/s. I think that 4MB/s speed using 1Gbps ethernet is far too slow.

I'm trying to profile this kernel thread, because I think that 100 jiffies is too much.
I'd like to ask if there is any way to tell how many times this kernel thread has been preempted?

Comment: Is your kernel compiled with `RT_PREEMPT` option enabled?

Comment: There is not such option in kernel config file, but uname -a shows: SMP PREEMPT.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "call" a thread? Your thread is sleeping and the interrupt handler awakens it? How long is your jiffy (usually this depends on HZ setting)? At typical settings, 100 jiffies would be a long time and your NIC should be able to receive tens of thousands of frames in that period (Gb ethernet is up to 1.488million fps).

Comment: @GilHamilton,  You might want to revise that calculation.  1gig bit is 125000000 bytes,  however, expect handshaking to consume 25percent, leaving 93750000 bytes,  at 1518 (typical max) size per frame is ~61758 frames/second.   gateways, routers, relays, all slow the transmission rate.  The length of the wire (like phone or cable wire) introduces distortion to the signal, which requires slowing the rate.  So while your internet interface may be able to run at 1gbit.  does not mean you can expect communication at such rates.

Comment: I said "up to". Yes, there are many factors that can slow transmission rates and still more that can slow reception. But at 64 byte frames, it's 1,488,095 frames / second. Network test appliances (Ixia, Spirent, etc) do this all day long. https://www.winpcap.org/misc/calculators.htm

Comment: @GilHamilton: yes - my thread is sleeping and interrupt awakens it from time to time. As I see my HZ option has value of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside the thread, you can give a try with the following `printk("preempt count is %d\n",current_thread_info()->preempt_count);`

You can add this at the entry of the thread and check the count difference between successive prints